# Cannot find bridge device with ifupdown

Tags: linux, network-interface, bridge, void-linux

Please note that I am using Void Linux.

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces.d/br0` file:

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
        bridge_waitport 0
        bridge_fd 0
```

However on boot I get this error:

```
=> Bringing up the network
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.2
Copyright 2004-2020 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Cannot find device "br0"
Failed to get interface index: No such device

If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
before submitting a bug. These pages explain the proper
process and the information we find helpful for debugging.

exiting.
ifup: failed to bring up br0
```

I have confirmed that I have `bridge-utils` installed. I am at a loss for what the problem here is. I would appreciate help.

Comment: I got same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I never found the solution. Are you using a Linux distro that doesn't use ifupdown by default?

Comment: No, using Debian Buster (v10). But I only have this problem on one server. Works fine on many others, so it's a little strange. Can see any different in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

(This is really a "comment" and not and answer, but it doesn't fit in the comment section)

It seems `ifup` doesn't create the bridge interface "behind the scene".

I expect it to do this:

```
ip link add name brLAN type bridge
ip link set brLAN up
ip link set eno1 master brLAN
ip link set eno1 up
```

And if the bridge use dhcp then:

```
dhclient brLAN
```